# SignalR and Sammy.js wrong behaviour in IE

Tags: javascript, signalr, sammy.js

In the SignalR's client event (javascipt function), I use sammy.setLocation("#xxx"); but IE10 navigated to a long url beginning with SignalR background request[1].
But Chrome works fine.

```
        var navigating = $.connection.navigatinghub;
        navigating.client.navigateInPage = function (url) {
            sammy.setLocation("#" + url);
        };
```

My goal is

```
http://localhost:30014/#xxx
```

But IE10 navigated to :

```
http://localhost:30014/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAtb8ox8I2WUGbubMEpY1ojgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABo9BEScEcfj7EykqEQM76utKY8Gykf0zUEfLdN%2Fj26hgAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAB0nlIDPLRfOgBH%2FltNOm5jURr0%2F%2Blluc4hnaG2wGQ8DTAAAAAJt7I28p7%2Bq5UeTiQXmnfB%2BbsQCgCqomTQKSXxYRt3LPIMq4gRwcscvuj0mTAXb2tAAAAA8QIiSemy27RcO8IuLr%2Feq5VpMSqEK%2BSX29Xvbm48o4yuNKeppsjFwHfmrMjq6eFwH0sFk4X8bbUkgRMZ3Uyjcw%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22navigatinghub%22%7D%5D&tid=10&frameId=1#xxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by SignalR calling your navigationInPage function from inside an [iframe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Hidden_iframe) who's url happens to be `http://localhost:30014/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame&...`.

`sammy.setLocation("#" + url);` is apparently using the iframe's url and as the prefix for your new location in IE.

`window.location.hash = "#" + url;` seems to work everywhere.

SignalR's forever frame transport [is only used in IE](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq#what-transports-does-signalr-use-in-various-browsers-to-mimic-a-real-time-connection) which is why you are only seeing this issue in that browser.

Comment: What a rapid and detailed explanation!